# Gunicorn ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsgi'

Tags: python, docker, flask

I ran the command sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 flask_api after creating a Docker image, but when I run docker ps, nothing shows up. The error message I received when building the Docker image is related to my Dockerfile, which is structured as follows:

```
# Use a base Python image
FROM python:3.8

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the project's requirements and install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the application code into the container
COPY . /app

# Set the port for the Flask application to run
EXPOSE 5000

# Command to start the application
CMD ["gunicorn", "wsgi:app", "-b", "0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

My folder struture:

```
project/
 |+---application
    |   +---wsgi.py
    |   +---routes.py
    |   +---other stuff
 |+---Dockerfile
 |+---requirements.txt
```

WSGI.PY:

```
from routes import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**ERROR:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsgi'**

Comment: "sudo docker" antipattern.  Why are you using sudo to run docker?

Comment: "No module named 'wsgi'" have you checked to verify that's in `requirements.txt`?

Comment: As you have the application structured, it looks like the Python module name should be `application.wsgi`.  Does changing that argument in your `CMD` help?

Comment: @erik258 Since it's very easy to use Docker to compromise the entire host system it's very reasonable to require `sudo` permissions for it.

Comment: @DavidMaze that Worked! I had to do it inside every import, must be bc now docker its working with "/app/application/wsgi.py"